# Update SQL query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have an issue where I need to update a field in a number of SQL Server tables.  The customer Order ID needs to be updated on all records that do not follow the standard format "C000001" (a letter followed by numbers). There are approximately 300 records that need changed (carry over records from a previous database version), as well as the corresponding linked tables.

I am a bit rusty on my SQL, so would like to verify the commands.

My proposed commands

```
UPDATE Customer_Order
SET ID = CONCAT('X', ID)
WHERE ID not like 'c%';

UPDATE Customer_Order_Line
SET Cust_Order_ID = CONCAT('X', Cust_Order_ID)
WHERE Cust_Order_ID not like 'c%';

UPDATE Quote_Order
SET Cust_Order_ID = CONCAT('X', Cust_Order_ID)
WHERE Cust_Order_ID not like 'c%';
```

etc... (I have approx 12 additional tables to update same as above)

Assistance is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: just do it manually... byt the time you get done typing it out someone still won't have posted a much better answer. It's just a one time thing anyways. You could select them all in a CTE and update the cte but that'll confuse you i suspect

Comment: So the columns you are updating have no foreign keys associated to them? Because I would expect a column named ID to be a primary key (at least in part). If that is the case, then this will not work.

Comment: Are the ID fields an integer datatype?

Comment: Yes this field is a Primary Key, though the above commands return the expected data

Comment: data type varchar(15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More of a formatted comment here..

Any time you want to do this, just make your update a select to verify your update:

```
SELECT ID, CONCAT('X', ID) as NewID
FROM Customer_Order
WHERE ID not like 'c%'
```

Make sure the `NewID` column is what you want to replace `ID` with.

Comment: That did as suspected, I will be trying against my other tables and also running in my test instance.  Many Thanks!

Comment: SELECT [CUST_ORDER_ID]
 ,CONCAT('X', [CUST_ORDER_ID]) as NewID
  FROM [INVTEST].[dbo].[QUOTE_ORDER]
  Where CUST_ORDER_ID not like 'c%'

Comment: @Technoid Teach a man to fish they say :)  Glad to provide the validation query you were missing.